# Magento2 XML: How to replace an <item> definition by another

Tags: magento2, xml

In order to change the checkout page summary item info, I need to replace in checkout_index_index.xml the following line `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>` in order to point to my own details.js file.

I then tried :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_index_index"/>
    <body>
            <referenceblock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceblock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but it is not working. The original details.js is called.

Thank you for your help

EDIT1 :

I tried for testing purpose to replace `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>` by `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/item/details</item>` in the core checkout_index_index.xml file and it works. So the problem is due to my module xml

Comment: Check with setup:upgrade and then deploy

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that. Not working...